# How to get damping matrix for structural model in FE analysis

Tags: finite-element, pde, matlab

I need to implement in C a method of obtaining transient solution of damped FE models based on modal results for a structural model (imported CAD geometry) defined with hysteretic (structural) damping. This method is also available in Matlab by using solve(model,tlist,"ModalResults",modalResultsVar);

However, the main problem is how to get damping matrix for this model (structural, not proportional from above defined hysteretic damping). It seems this was solved and implemented in Matlab. Every route I took from the below listed in solving this problem, finally appears to be problematic:

1. I cannot find any information how the above mentioned application of solve function was implemented in Matlab,
2. I tried to get this damping matrix using assembleFEMatrices in Matlab function but it does not give damping matrix despite its usage in structural model as hysteretic damping,
3. I tested reduce function based on Craig-Bampton reduction method, but it similarly does not give damping matrix, only stiffness and mass matrices,
4. I was checking if modal analysis performed for a damped model (hysteretic damping) can return any information about damping, but I suppose it does not.

Do you have any clue how to solve this problem and get the full data about the model or the algorithm for C implementation ?
Thanks, Piotr

Edit: The most promising idea so far it seems to me to get stiffness, mass and damping matrices from geometry mesh in the same way as matlab function assembleFEMatrices assuming hysterestic damping for the model. I believe it was already solved and used in many tools but I am not able to reach the proper document.

Comment: What does Rdm and R stand for?

Comment: Rdm and R are just arbitrary names of variables. In the described case R stands for a solution of modal analysis obtained using Matlab: R = solve(model) (here model is defined using createpde function with an option structural="modal-solid". Rdm is the used after switching model to transient analysis by structural="trasient-solid".

Comment: See also edited version of the presented question.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking. Exactly what is the form of your damping data? Do you want to perform a transient analysis using the modes from an eigenvalue analysis or with the complete stiffness and mass matrices?

Comment: If they are arbitrary names of variables, I would suggest yo edit the question without them.

Comment: To Nicoguaro: The question was edited according to you comment.

Comment: To Bill Greene: The main problem now it seems that I need to obtain mass, stiffness and damping matrices assuming I have data about geometry with selected mesh and parameters of the material such as YoungsModulus, PissonsRatio, MassDensity and HystereticDamping. Or maybe damping matrix can be calculated based on other parameters in such a case of hysteretic damping. I am looking for any hint. If it is not possible I am looking for a nice source to study how it is done with stiffness and mass matrix only to understand this method more and maybe reach the solution in future.